# Android crash report: java.lang.IllegalStateException on Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, crash

I have an app that uses google mobile vision(OCR), Camera and Flashlight,
lately i keep getting crashes report almost everyday on Android 6.0 Devices.

here's the report :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)

  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5293)

  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21660)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:227)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6100)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:859)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:749)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 

  at java.lang.reflect.Field.get (Native Method)

  at myPacName.instantscanandrecharge.CamActivity.changeFlashStatus (CamActivity.java:412)
```

i don't know what to do with the native method in this report

but from my own code the method that causes this error is :

```
public void changeFlashStatus(View v) {


    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                camera = (Camera) field.get(camSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    params = camera.getParameters();

                    if(!isFlash){
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        flash_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_flash_on);

                        isFlash = true;
                    } else {
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        flash_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_flash_off);

                        isFlash = false;

                    }
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                }

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

why it's not working with Android 6.0 ?

Comment: Its `java.lang.NullPointerException` you have catch only `IllegalAccessException` this is why its crashing . Debug your code find out null object access .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i see nothing wrong with my method i'm really confused , i mean i already check if camera != null